# PowerVault MD 1000 raid 5 with three physical disks one failed and virtual disk become "failed"

Tags: dell-powervault

I have a Power Vault MD 1000 which includes a RAID 5 array (I inherited it), open manage server administrator reports the structure as RAID 5. Today one of the three disks failed.

I would have expected it to become "Degraded". But I got failed virtual disk. And, on omsa, I only have the options "Delete..." , "Blink" , "Unblink". I googled up and down, left and right and I could not find no page explaining in what circumstances one physical drive causes full virtual drive to fail. All pages said it requires two. Beside those three drives I have a fourth one that is "foreign". Here's what I did so far :

- removed the faulty drive (orange led)
- borrowed a working drive from another machine and inserted it
- System reported both foreign drives, but virtual disk remained "failed".
- I cleaned foreign and both drives become ready (the other two that belong to vdisk are online), again v disk continued failed.

I removed the "new" drive and inserted the old one, I was expecting the old drive to become "failed" as before, but it became "foreign" rather. But the main problem remains, the v drive continues "failed", not degraded. Is there someway to rebuild it? I have backups of most but not of everything, unfortunately.

Comment: The MD1000 doesn't have a raid controller

Comment: hi, Jacob, in my case omreport reports PERC 6/E, is this other kind of controller ?

Answer (score 0):

I Carlos,
stressful situation....and probably needs a deep investigation it's no easy by mail.
But I don't understand the status of your RAID right now, so If I remember right, in a case on my customer you need to import the "foreign" disk on VDISK then when the action is successful, everything will be restored. (crossfinger)
I hope that it helps.
:-)

Comment: Francesco, thanks for your help. the status of my 4 pdisks are 0 - OK/Ready , 1-OK/Foreign (with failure predicted) , 2-Online , 3 - online and this state translates (no idea how, Im lost here) on a vdisk that is critical / Failed. I exported the logs from the controller (PERC 6/E in my case) greped for bad,error,nothing came up. Your competent advise much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, it seems that when we have a foreign drive, one cannot do nothing until that foreign drive issue is addressed. I tried to apply the action importrecoverforeignconfig to the controller, and after a while the vdisk transitioned from failed to degraded :
omconfig storage controller action=importrecoverforeignconfig controller=1

After a reboot, disk mounted OK.

interesting read from dell site, though the original problem is not exactly the same : http://lists.us.dell.com/pipermail/linux-poweredge/2008-September/037379.html

Best,
Carlos